# MODULE_NOT_FOUND with "paths" defined in required tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

When executing my transpiled code using imports defined in my root `tsconfig.json`, `nodejs` throws the a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error.

The background of this problem is that I'd like the compiled outputs of the client and of the api folders to share the contents of shared.
My aproach is to have a `tsconfig.json` in the project root, where `compilerOptions.baseUrl` and `compilerOptions.paths` are set (among other options). This file is then included in the corresponding `tsconfig.json` in `api/` and `client/` through `extends`.
VSCode resolves the imports correctly.

`test.ts`:

```
export class Test {
    public greet(msg: string) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
import { Test } from '@shared/test'

let a: Test = new Test();
a.greet("Hello!")
```

root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"],
      "@api/*": ["api/src/*"],
      "@client/*": ["client/src*"]
    },
  ...
  }
}
```

tsc call:

```
# From the project root
$ tsc --project client/tsconfig.json
```

Project tree:

```
$ tree -a -F -I 'node_modules|dist' .
.
├── api/
│   ├── src/
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── client/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── shared/
│   └── test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Error:

```
$ node client/dist/client/src/index.js 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@shared/test'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/typescript-test/client/dist/client/src/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/typescript-test/client/dist/client/src/index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/src/typescript-test/client/dist/client/src/index.js' ]
}

Node.js v17.6.0
```

Comment: Do you have `include` set in your root tsconfig.json?

Comment: @BigG no I don't

Comment: You may need to set include to, well, include your src directory and/or any other directory you want to include. (Sorry for the abundant amount of "includes" there are haha) Also are you using Lerna or some other monorepo build tool?

Comment: @BigG Well the file in `shared` is being transpiled, but the module is not being found none the less.
No, I'm not using any monorepo. I wanted to try to implement this just with TS, since I didn't want to add more complexity.

Comment: Hmm, this is very odd. Do you know if the path stays the same after build or is it correctly changed to the absolute path? Here is a good medium article I found about it. Not the best solution, but it could work. https://medium.com/@zzpzaf.se/typescript-how-to-solve-the-problem-with-unresolved-path-aliases-in-transpiled-js-files-a11c76fb371a

Comment: ./client/

├── dist/

│   ├── client/

│   │   └── src/

│   │       └── index.js

│   └── shared/

│       └── test.js

├── src/

│   └── index.ts

└── tsconfig.json

Comment: What I find weird, is that in `dist` there is a `client` folder as well as a `shared` folder

Comment: That is very strange. I would suggest copying the project into Lerna and compile just to see what happens and compare against your basic tsc project.